# Implementing a lookup table that takes T and returns attributes on method of type List<T>

Tags: c#, lookup-tables

I have a class that manages collections of objects e.g. `List<Car>` and `List<Bike>` which are atribute.

I'd like to find a way to get a reference to each of those collections in a lookup so I can implement methods such as `Add<Car>(myCar)` or `Add(myCar)` (with reflection) and it will add it to the right collection.

I tried the following,

```
public class ListManager 
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<object>>> _lookup 
        = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<object>>>();

    public ListManager()
    {
        this._lookup.Add(typeof(Car), () => { return this.Cars.Cast<object>().ToList(); });
        this._lookup.Add(typeof(Bike), () => { return this.Bikes.Cast<object>().ToList(); });
    }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

but `.ToList()` creates a new list and not a reference, so `_lookup[typeof(Car)]().Add(myCar)` is only added to the dictionary list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
public class ListManager
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IList> _lookup
        = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();

    public ListManager()
    {
        _lookup.Add(typeof(Car), new List<Car>());
        _lookup.Add(typeof(Bike), new List<Bike>());
    }

    public List<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return (List<Car>)_lookup[typeof(Car)]; }
    }

    public List<Bike> Bikes
    {
        get { return (List<Bike>)_lookup[typeof(Bike)]; }
    }

    public void Add<T>(T obj)
    {
        if(!_lookup.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) throw new ArgumentException("obj");
        var list = _lookup[typeof(T)];

        list.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

It would be nice if both `Car` and `Bike` are derived from the same class or implement the same interface. Then you can add type constraint to the `Add` method to get compile errors instead of `ArgumentException`.

**Edit**

There is a small problem with the simple solution above. It will only work if the type of the objects added to the list is exactly the type stored in the `_lookup` dictionary. If you try to add an object derived from `Car` or `Bike` it will throw.

For example if you define a class

```
public class Batmobile : Car { }
```

Then

```
var listManager = new ListManager();
listManager.Add(new Batmobile());
```

will throw `ArgumentException`.

To avoid it you will need a more complicated type lookup method. Instead of simple `_lookup[typeof(Car)]` it should be:

```
private IList FindList(Type type)
{
    // find all lists of type, any of its base types or implemented interfaces
    var candidates = _lookup.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();

    if (candidates.Count == 1) return candidates[0].Value;

    // return the list of the lowest type in the hierarchy
    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
    {
        if (candidates.Count(kvp => candidate.Key.IsAssignableFrom(kvp.Key)) == 1)
            return candidate.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Great follow-up, this is the kind of thing that would have driven me crazy in debugging

Answer (score 3):

Try the following approach:

```
public class ListManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IList> _lookup = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();

    public ListManager()
    {
        _lookup.Add(typeof(Car), new List<Car>());
        _lookup.Add(typeof(Bike), new List<Bike>());
    }

    public List<T> Get<T>()
    {
        return _lookup[typeof(T)] as List<T>;
    }

    public void Add<T>(T item)
    {
        Get<T>().Add(item);
    }

    public List<Car> Cars
    {
        get {  return Get<Car>(); }
    }

    public List<Bike> Bikes
    {
        get { return Get<Bike>(); }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var listManager = new ListManager();
listManager.Add(new Car());
```

---

### About derived classes

If you have some class derived from the `Car`, for example:

```
public class Ferrari : Car { }
```

And for some reason you don't want to have a `List<Ferrari>` in the dictionary, but you want to add `Ferrari` to the `List<Car>`. Then you should specify the generic type argument explicitly:

```
listManager.Add<Car>(new Ferrari());
```

*It's important that the compiler checks that `Ferrari` is a `Car` at compile time, so you cannot add `Ferrari` to `List<Bike>`.*

But in this case it is possible that you'll forget to specify a generic type argument somewhere and therefore you'll get an exception at run time.
To avoid it, just remove the `Add<T>` method. Thus you'll must explicitly specify a type of the collection each time:

```
listManager.Get<Car>().Add(new Ferrari());
```

*But all the type checks will be performed at compile time.*

Moreover, using the last approach you are able to manipulate lists as you like, since the `Get<T>` method returns a reference to the fully-functional `List<T>` (not just pure non-generic `IList`):

```
List<Car> cars = listManager.Get<Car>();
cars.Add(new Ferrari());
var coolCars = cars.OfType<Ferrari>();
```

So you don't need to reinvent the wheel by reimplementing `List<T>` methods in the `ListManager`.

Comment: @Brendan I've updated the answer for the case of derived classes. Please revise.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate all **ListManager** properties and filter by its type. This is a working example:

```
public class Car
{
     public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
public class Bike
{
    public int Pedals { get; set; }
}

public class ListManager
{
    //Defina all list properties here:
    public List<Car> Car { get; } = new List<Car>();
    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; } = new List<Bike>();

    //Gets a list instance by its element type
    public object GetList(Type ElemType)
    {
        //Get the first property that is of the generic type List<> and that it's first generic argument equals ElemType,
        //then, obtain the value for that property
        return GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x =>
           x.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
           x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) &&
           x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == ElemType).FirstOrDefault().GetValue(this);
    }

    public void Add(object Value)
    {

        var ElemType = Value.GetType();
        var List = GetList(ElemType);
        //If list had more Add method overloads you should get all of them and filter by some other criteria
        var AddMethod = List.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

        //Invoke the Add method for the List instance with the first parameter as Value
        AddMethod.Invoke(List,new [] { Value });
    }
}
```

And the test console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var L = new ListManager();

        L.Add(new Car { Wheels = 4 });
        L.Add(new Car { Wheels = 3 });
        L.Add(new Bike { Pedals = 2 });

        //Prints 2:
        Console.WriteLine(L.Car.Count);

        //Prints 1:
        Console.WriteLine(L.Bikes.Count);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Note: ** The GetList method could be cached using a Dictionary for improving its performance, since it will return always the same instance for the same type